# Getting information from cloud flare on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cloudflare

i want to write an Android Flutter program that works online:
Have an admin panel and a user panel. The user panel does not require registration.
The admin is the owner of the restaurant who determines in his own panel whether the restaurant is busy or not. And users see the message entered by the admin.
How to do this in Flutter with the help of Cloud Flare

How can I write such a program?